# Что за ошибка? IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, python-2.x, numpy

Хочу узнать размер изображения. Решение следующее: с помощью `pgmagick` открываю изображение и сохраняю его в массив:

```
img = Image('image_1.jpeg')
```

и с помощью `numpy` узнаю размер:

```
width=np.size(img,0)
height = np.size(img,1)
```

В результате вижу такую ошибку:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/alex/PycharmProjects/untitled/create_file_annotation.py", line
> 56, in 
> width=np.size(img,0)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line
> 2702, in size
> return asarray(a).shape[axis] IndexError: tuple index out of range

А самое интересное, что я поставил `print weight,height` и перед ошибкой размер изображения выдается правильный, в чем может быть причина ошибки? `Python` использую версии **2.7**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эта ошибка возникает когда `np.size()` получает в качестве первого аргумента НЕ `array_like` объект, например:

```
In [58]: np.size(111, 0)
...
skipped
...
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

`img` является объектом класса `pgmagic.Image`.

[Решение](https://pythonhosted.org/pgmagick/cookbook.html#get-image-size):

```
width, height = img.width, img.height
```

Comment: А что это за атрибуты такие, width и height? Откуда их нужно брать?

Comment: @АлексейАникеев, вы [ссылку](https://pythonhosted.org/pgmagick/cookbook.html#get-image-size) открывали?

Comment: Прошу прощения за не внимательность! Большое спасибо, все заработало.